# Oracle PL/SQL Convert string into INTEGER (maximum value 2147483648)

Tags: string, integer

Please suppose you have a VARCHAR2 string of 6 character so composed:

LETTER LETTER DIGIT LETTER LETTER LETTER

where LETTER = A, B, C, ....., W, X, Y, Z
and
NUMBER = 0, 1, 2, 3, ....., 9

The minimum string with the previous rules is: AA0AAA
The maximum string with the previous rules is: ZZ9ZZZ

The number of possible combinations is:

26 * 26 * 10 * 26 * 26 * 26 = 118813760

How can I decode AA0AAA to 1, AA0AAB to 2, AA0AAC to 3, ....., ZZ9ZZZ to 118813760?

I am programming in Oracle PL/SQL.

Thank you in advance for your kind cooperation.

This is my code but it is not optimized :(

```
SELECT   RIGA
  FROM   (SELECT   ROWNUM riga, alfa.*
            FROM   (WITH s1 AS (SELECT   'A' list1 FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'B' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'C' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'D' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'E' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'F' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'G' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'H' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'I' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'J' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'K' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'L' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'M' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'N' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'O' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'P' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'Q' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'R' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'S' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'T' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'U' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'V' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'W' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'X' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'Y' FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT   'Z' FROM DUAL),
                        s2 AS (SELECT   'A' list2 FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'B' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'C' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'D' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'E' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'F' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'G' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'H' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'I' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'J' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'K' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'L' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'M' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'N' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'O' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'P' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'Q' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'R' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'S' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'T' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'U' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'V' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'W' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'X' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'Y' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'Z' FROM DUAL),
                        k1 AS (SELECT   '0' list3 FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   '1' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   '2' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   '3' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   '4' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   '5' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   '6' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   '7' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   '8' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   '9' FROM DUAL),
                        s3 AS (SELECT   'A' list4 FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'B' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'C' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'D' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'E' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'F' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'G' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'H' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'I' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'J' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'K' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'L' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'M' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'N' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'O' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'P' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'Q' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'R' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'S' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'T' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'U' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'V' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'W' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'X' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'Y' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'Z' FROM DUAL),
                        s4 AS (SELECT   'A' list5 FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'B' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'C' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'D' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'E' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'F' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'G' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'H' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'I' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'J' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'K' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'L' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'M' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'N' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'O' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'P' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'Q' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'R' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'S' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'T' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'U' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'V' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'W' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'X' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'Y' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'Z' FROM DUAL),
                        s5 AS (SELECT   'A' list6 FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'B' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'C' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'D' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'E' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'F' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'G' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'H' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'I' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'J' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'K' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'L' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'M' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'N' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'O' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'P' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'Q' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'R' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'S' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'T' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'U' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'V' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'W' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'X' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'Y' FROM DUAL
                               UNION ALL
                               SELECT   'Z' FROM DUAL)
                    SELECT   *
                      FROM   S1,
                             S2,
                             K1,
                             S3,
                             S4,
                             S5) alfa)
 WHERE       LIST1 = 'A'
         AND LIST2 = 'A'
         AND LIST3 = '1'
         AND LIST4 = 'A'
         AND LIST5 = 'A'
         AND LIST6 = 'A';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on `SQL Developer`, input is in variable `in_string`:

```
declare   
   in_string varchar2(20):= 'ZZ9ZZZ';

   type m IS VARRAY(6) OF INTEGER;
   weights m;
   in_char char(1);
   cnt number := 0;
   res number := 1;
BEGIN
   weights:= m(4569760, 175760, 17576, 676, 26, 1);
   while (cnt < length(in_string))
      loop
        cnt := cnt + 1;
        in_char := substr(in_string, cnt, 1);

        if cnt != 3 then
           res := res + (ASCII(in_char) - 65) * weights(cnt);
        else
           res := res + (ASCII(in_char) - 48) * weights(cnt);
        end if;

   end loop;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(res);
END;
/
```

which gives me: 118813760.

Comment: At present I receive the message, "You may award your bounty in 1 hour".

Comment: I glad you liked, especially that I didn't use PL/SQL too much... ok I can wait 1h :)

Comment: See you this evening with 500 points award, I won't forget!!  Thank you again!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ascii function to convert from a letter to a number.
'A' = 65 in ascii, 'Z' = 90.
So substract 64 from the result and you have the correct value.

Then for the number, add 1 to it (0 maps to 1, 9 maps to 10)

**see edit below, this part is not correct**

Multiply all parts, and voila: this is a SQL-only solution.
Much-much faster than declaring a PL/SQL function, because then for each result the DB has to switch between SQL and PL/SQL context.

```
select t.string input 
,      to_number(ascii(substr(t.string,1,1))-64)
     * to_number(ascii(substr(t.string,2,1))-64)
     * (to_number(substr(t.string,3,1)) + 1)
     * to_number(ascii(substr(t.string,4,1))-64)
     * to_number(ascii(substr(t.string,5,1))-64)
     * to_number(ascii(substr(t.string,6,1))-64) as value
from (select 'AA0AAA' string from dual
      union all
      select 'ZZ9ZZZ' string from dual
      ) t;
select ascii('Z') from dual;
```

**EDIT - improved answer**
I saw the answer of ProblemFactory. And he is doing it right: there is a weighing factor.
I.e. AA0ZZZ should be lower than ZZ0ZAA while the version above returns the same.
However, in his solution there is a need for a declared PL/SQL function, which will lead to a big performance penalty when executed for a large data set.

The following query will return the correct value (with thanks to ProblemFactory):

```
select t.string input 
,    to_number(ascii(substr(t.string,1,1))-65)    * 4569760 --26*26*26*10*26
     +  to_number(ascii(substr(t.string,2,1))-65) * 175760  --26*26*26*10
     + to_number(substr(t.string,3,1))            * 17576   --26*26*26
     + to_number(ascii(substr(t.string,4,1))-65)  * 676     --26*26
     + to_number(ascii(substr(t.string,5,1))-65)  * 26
     + to_number(ascii(substr(t.string,6,1))-64) as value
from (select 'AA0AAA' string from dual
      union all
      select 'ZZ9ZZZ' string from dual
      ) t;
```

results in

```
INPUT       VALUE
------ ----------
AA0AAA          1 
ZZ9ZZZ  118813760
```

Comment: Thank you very much for having transformed ProblemFactory's answer in a single select statement :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your string format is fixed, you could break this down by writing a much simpler pl/sql function that takes in a single letter and returns the number of that letter - e.g., A=0, Z=25.

If you know what position that letter had in your string, you can work out how much that letter is worth individually, and then multiply it by the power of 26 that is appropriate to that position.

Answer (score 0):

If this turns out to be a hard problem in PL/SQL, there is a MixedRadixNumber java class available in [aima](http://aima-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/aima-all/release/javadoc/aima-core/aima/core/util/math/MixedRadixNumber.html).

It is certainly possible to call out to java from within PL/SQL, as documented in this [O'Reilly book](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596514464/Chapters_27and28_OPLSQL5e.pdf).

Comment: I need the solution in PL/SQL, sorry.